# Identifying old Thermal Relay and its operating parameters

Tags: identification, components, datasheet, mains

I was hoping that I could get help identifying an electrical component from a environmental chamber over 30 years old. It is a Sunvic Thermal Relay Type TDW-AJ 2301, 17A 200/250V AC as shown in the pictures.

[image: Sunvic Thermal relay Top]

[image: Sunvic Thermal relay Side]

As it is also marked Made In Great Britain and made from a brown plastic(possible Bakelite) it could be older than 30 years. There is a embossed marking on the case of 24 C. The insides are seen here.
[image]

Pins 4 and 5 are connected to a heater coil, pins 2 and 3 are a relay switch.
It is used to latch on mains power 240V ac to the the rest of the components by pressing a momentary reset switch. Mains power is applied between pins 4 and 5 heating up the heat coil, causing pins 2 and 3 to make a closed contact. If it has been running long enough and there is enough retained heat for a short mains power disconnection to allow it a restart without pressing the reset switch.
As it is old I have been having difficulty finding exact data on it operation, e.g. how long it can retain it latched status and if the heater degrading. Most google searchers find thermal relays that do the opposite breaking connection due to overloads.

I know this part may need to be replaced but I would like to know if my observations of its operation are the same as the datasheet.